# Prove that for any $f:A\times A\to A$ and $B\subseteq A$, the closure of $B$ under $f$ exists.

Tags: functions, solution-verification, induction

$Proof$.
Define the sets $B_n$ by $B_1=B$ and for every $n\ge 1$, $B_{n+1}=f(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B_{n}\times\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B_{n})$. Let $C=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_{i}$. We show that $C$ is the closure of $B$ under $f$.

- $B\subseteq C\subseteq A$.
  Clearly $B=B_1\subseteq C$. And since every $B_i\subseteq A$, then $C\subseteq A$.
- $C$ is closed under $f$
  Take any $x,y\in C$. Then $(x,y)\in B_j\times B_k$ for some $j,k$ by definition of $C$. Without loss of generality suppose $j<k$. Then $(x,y)\in\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_i\times\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_i$, and so $f(x,y)\in f(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_i\times\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_i)=B_{k+1}$. Therefore $f(x,y)\in\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i=C$, and hence $C$ is closed under $f$.
- $C$ is the minimum
  Suppose that $D$ is a set with $B\subseteq D\subseteq A$, and that $D$ is closed under $f$. We prove by induction that for any $k\ge 1$, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}B_i\subseteq D$.
  $Base$: For $k=1$, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{1}B_i=B\subseteq D$ by assumption.
  $Step$: Suppose $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}B_i\subseteq D$ and $f(x,y)\in B_{k+1}=f(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_{i}\times\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_{i})$. Then $(x,y)\in\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_{i}\times\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_{i}\subseteq D\times D$, which means $f(x,y)\in D$, since $D$ is closed under $f$. Therefore $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}B_i\cup B_{k+1}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}B_i\subseteq D$.

Is my proof valid? I'm curious especially about the induction part, does it work? I haven't studied infinity yet, but if I show that a property holds for when the limit is any natural number, does it prove that the property holds when the limit is infinity? What i mean is that $C$ is defined to have infinity as limit.

Comment: What exactly do you want to prove, i.e., what do you mean with "the closure of $B$ under $f$ exists"? How can a closure not exist?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're thinking of $f$ as a binary operation, so that the **closure** of $B$ under $f$ means "the smallest superset $K\supseteq B$ contained in $A$ such that $f(b,b')\in K$ for all $b,b'\in B$."

(If you haven't already done so, it's worthwhile to prove that this is well-defined. That is, that if $B\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq C'$ with $C$ and $C'$ closed, then there is some $C''$ that is contained in both $C$ and $C'$, such that also $B\subseteq C''$. Hint: Take $C''=C\cap C'$. Yes, it is a routine argument... but it is worth the self-confidence that you can provide such details, since this subtlety appears in many definitions.)

---

The first two steps are perfect! Nicely done.

The third step is almost entirely correct. The statement "$\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}B_i\subseteq D$ for any $k\geq 1$" would indeed prove the minimality condition, the base case is correct, and the inductive step is morally correct as well. However there is a (possible) small but significant, *conceptual* error in the first sentence. I'll explain this in the next section.

Before that, I want to address your question about infinity, which is more interesting.

> If I show that a property holds for when the limit is any natural number, does it prove that the property holds when the limit is infinity?

This is a very insightful question, as well as an important one: the answer is **NO**!

An overly-slick example is the property of "being finte" itself: if $B_i=\{i\}$, then every $\cup_{i=0}^n B_i$ is finite for all $n$, but $\cup_{i=0}^\infty B_i =\mathbb{N}$, which is not.

The reason why we're okay in this problem is essentially that union is an operation that works with each element of the set individually, rather than all at once. More precisely, by definition, if $\mathscr{B}$ is any set of subsets of $A$, then
$$ \bigcup \mathscr{B} := \{z\in A: \exists B\in\mathscr{B}, z\in B\}.$$
(This is a *surprisingly* "low-level" definition in modern math: the existence of such sets is an *axiom* of ZFC!)

When $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n: n\in\mathbb{N}^+\}$ it is traditional to define  the change of notation that appears in this problem, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n := \bigcup\mathscr{B}$. Therefore, our statement that
$C=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n \subseteq D$ means:
$$ \forall z\in A ~\exists n\in\mathbb{N}^+, z\in B_n \implies z\in D. $$

The point is that for each $z\in C$, there must exist a choice of $n$ which makes it so, and thus $z\in \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i$.

However, notice that each choice is independent: there need not be any *consistency* between these choices. The "is infinite" property *does* require such a consistency.

(To avoid defining infinity, let me tell a parable that captures the difficulty. To count the number of elements in a set, I need to point at them and name them with a number, and the highest number I reach is how many elements there are. Pointing at $\{*\}$, I say "1", and pointing at $\{+\}$, I also say "1". But when I point at $\{*,+\}$, I say "1, 2", giving one of the symbols a new name! This is the sort of inconsistency which "being finite" is sensitive to, but "being a subset of" is not.)

---

The first sentence of the inductive step should read:

> Suppose $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}B_i\subseteq D$ and $z\in B_{k+1}$.

One of the most common errors in inductive proofs is that instead of starting with something in the $n+1$ case and reducing it to the $n$ case, people will start with something in the $n$ case and build it up to the $n+1$ case. This is only valid if you can prove that (1) everything in the $n+1$ case can be built up from the $n$ case— already false for many interesting problems! and (2) the method of "building up" in the proof completely captures everything in the $n+1$ case.

The proof *looks* as though you are committing this error.* To avoid the appearance of this impropriety, the inductive setup should not be using the fact that $z$ has the form $f(x,y)$. It does, of course, but this is a consequence of the definition of $B_{k+1}$, so you should say that separately.

[* It's not clear to me that you *actually* misunderstood the induction structure, but that's not necessarily relevant. Proofs are pieces of communication: what matters is how convincing you are to your (skeptical but good-faith) reader. I think a reader in your target audience could reasonably say "I don't believe this induction works; it is clearly malformed". ]

Comment: Im gonna be honest, i dont understand anything that you are saying in the infinity section. So you start by saying that the answer to my question is no, but doesn't my proof depend on the answer being yes? In my proof, I show that the property holds when the limit is any natural number, which then proves that the property also holds for when the limit is infinity? I dont understand the point of the overly-slick example. When you say: "The reason why we're okay in this problem", are you trying to explain why the proof works in this case, even though the answer to the infinity question is no?

Comment: I think i understand it a little better now. So your overly-slick example shows why the answer to the question is no, e.g if you prove that $\bigcup_{i=0}^{n}B_{i}$ is finite for all $n$, it doesnt mean $\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}B_{i}$ is finite. Then you explain why it works in my proof, but i dont fully understand your explanation.

Comment: I dont fully understand the inconsistency and consistency thing. You say: "notice that each choice is independent: there need not be any consistency between these choices.", what is the significance of this? Then you say: "The "is infinite" property does require such a consistency.", what is this consistency? I dont really understand the parable you made, could you explain how does this inconsistency/consistency thing appear in the overly-slick example?

Comment: Re #2: Yes, you understand correctly: in general the answer is "No, arbitrarily large does not imply infinite", but for this example there is no difference. Re #3: Sorry, but you've made it clear that you haven't yet gotten around to grappling with formal definitions of infinity— which is fine! But it does mean that I'm hesitant to elaborate too much on my "consistency" analogy; ultimately I just wanted it to be another perspective that you could keep in mind when you are able to consider these definitions more carefully.

Comment: @bobbyJames That said, I'm happy to elaborate on my explanation for this specific problem. To reiterate from my Answer: they key point here is that the definition of $C$ means nothing more than $z\in C$ is in some $B_n$ for finite $n$. So to show that $C$ is a subset of $D$ we need to do exactly what you did; namely show that $B_n$ is a subset of $D$ for every $n$. Your concern (again, *a priori*, a reasonable one!) is that maybe the infinity means that this procedure fails to test some element of $C$. But the definition of $C$ is such that it does not.

Comment: To say this in even more problem-specific terms: informally the question your proof is resolving is: "Is it really true that I can close a set just by performing the operation on that set over and over again?" For instance, the closure of $\{2\}$ under addition is $2\mathbb{N}^+$. To worry that "over and over again" doesn't catch everything is essentially to ask whether the *infinite* sum $2+2+2+\cdots$ should also be in there. The answer is no, even if you allow "infinite integers", because by definition a closed set need only be closed under finite sums.